# Apache camel retry logic while polling from remote server

Tags: apache-camel

I am trying to pull files from a remote server and if not able to connect to remote server want to implement below scenarios:

1. Would like to retry 'N' times,
2. If the connection is not successful after retrying want to stop polling and throw an exception to consumer saying "Server is not responding"

Comment: Add a bean which records this information in a text file, database or some other persistent store and then raises the alarm when conditions are met.

Comment: I know I am asking too much but could you please share some example please.

Answer (score 1):

In your route you need a bean that connects to the remote server. If it can't connect, it should through an exception.

Then add an onException handler in your route
onException(CannotConnectException.class)
.maximumRedeliveries(3)
.processRef("doSomething")

The "doSomething" process has to take care of stop polling and inform consumer part of the route. For example, to stop polling you could call a method of the connection bean to stop it polling. The best solution is really going to depend on how you rest of your system fits together.

Comment: Nice and clean. Good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a polling strategy for this. So the commit and rollback methods will decide on what to do if there is an issue with the route of some sort